# Automated Unit test case generation for UWP app

Tags: c#, unit-testing, win-universal-app

I have a uwp app source code, it has to be unit tested, writing the test case for existing source code will take lot of time, i am looking to generate automated unit test cases , something similar to intellitest present for classic desktop apps in visual studio. can anybody give an idea how to generate automatic unit test cases for the uwp app source code. Is there any nuget package or tool available to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible for now.

Just for now you can use Unit test framework.

I tried to do the same 2 weeks ago without success 
.